# How to allow unicode while uploading through media manager in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am not being able to upload the image file which is in Nepalese language thourgh media manger of joomla 3x. How can I make it happen? Is there any way?

Comment: I think you might have more success asking on [https://joomla.stackexchange.com/](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/). But you should explain what happens exactly - do you get an error, if so which one etc.

Comment: Agree with @MrLister  but image upload is very conservative in its security checking since uploads are so potentially dangerous.  I am sure that it has a limited set of characters.   That said you may want to check options or consider translating to punycode.